# how to overcome delay in Wifi Connection android programmatically?

Tags: android, wifi

Whenever I need to connected to wifi accesspoint.It will take time and some times gives unsuccessfull 0r disconnected state.But i need to connect Wifi immediatly within seconds.Every time I disconnect or disable wifi using WifiManager.disconnect() or wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false) then all Accesspoints are dissappear from wifiSettings screen.Again whenever enable the network it scans all accesspoints,configured networks and wifiManager shows to me while connecting the network 'obtaining the IP adress of network and after obtaining the ip address it tries to connect.So here getting late to connect the Wifi.Is there any alternative to remedy this problem please give me response ASAP?

Comment: AFAIK I know that's how WIFI chips work nowadays, and you can't speed that up.

Answer (score 0):

You have TTL (time to live) in the router could be set to low, and the normal DHCP setup time if it doesnt know your IP number shouldnt be more than 3-5seconds for a strong signal. If you have this task in the main UI then you need to consider putting it in a asynch task.  I have found that a faster cpu'd phone does plow through the connection setup faster.  The 600mhz phone takes 5 seconds to setup a first time wifi connection. The dual core 1.2Ghz takes 2-3seconds. Both using the same AP (Access Point).